# Change the progress bar of youtube api android

Tags: android, youtube, progress-bar

I have just successfully implemented the YouTube API for android. Now I need to customize the progress bar that is shown just before the video plays. I have been researching and not come across a suitable answer yet. Does YouTube let me do this? If not, is there a work around that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess there is no such an API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK There is no such API that provides facility to update or customize the youtube API uptill now. Basically its core implementation part of youtube api , so you can not customize it.